# Nginx reverse proxy not working with dynamic proxy_pass

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am attempting to use an nginx reverse proxy to proxy up to the AWS API and am hitting an issue where if I statically define the upstream server, it works perfectly, but if I attempt to generate it dynamically it throws a 502 Bad Gateway error. I am unsure how to fix this issue.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # Logging
        ##

        log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $host $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name to: $upstream_addr ($upstream_http_name): $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com (.*)\.colinaws\.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.log upstreamlog;

        location / {
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.amazonaws.com;
                }
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.$2.amazonaws.com;
                }
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.$2.amazonaws.com;
                }
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Target;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Date;
                proxy_pass_header User-Agent;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
                proxy_pass_header Accept-Encoding;
        }
}
```

In the above configuration it does not work, but if I go ahead and statically define the `proxy_pass` as an AWS endpoint (say http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com) it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here was that `proxy_pass` was not set to a standalone variable and there was no `resolver` flag set. The addition of both of these items forces nginx to re-resolve the URL every passthrough instead of caching the IP address on the onset. My final (stable) configuration looks like this:

```
server {
        # Listen on port 80, this will be updated to port 443 once ssl is enabled
        listen 80;

        # Server names should map to incoming requests so we can regex process out the service and
        # region later
        server_name (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com;

        # Log the incoming information for debug purposes. The formatter 'upstreamlog' can be found in
        # the config root at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        #access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.log upstreamlog;

        # Need to have a DNS server to resolve the FQDNs provided to proxy_pass
        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        # Parse the incoming FQDN and determine the upstream server
        if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                set $upstream http://$1.amazonaws.com;
        }
        if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                set $upstream http://$1.$2.amazonaws.com;
        }

        # Proxy the request upstream
        location / {
                proxy_pass $upstream;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Target;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Date;
                proxy_pass_header User-Agent;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
                proxy_pass_header Accept-Encoding;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com (.*)\.colinaws\.com;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/proxy.log upstreamlog;

        location / {
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.amazonaws.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
                }
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.$2.amazonaws.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
                }
                if ($host ~* (.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)\.colinaws\.com) {
                        proxy_pass http://$1.$2.amazonaws.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
                }
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass_header Authorization;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Target;
                proxy_pass_header X-Amz-Date;
                proxy_pass_header User-Agent;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
                proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
                proxy_pass_header Accept-Encoding;
        }
}
```

When you use variables in `proxy_pass` you need to provide complete uri and args also

Comment: This was not the issue, I managed to solve it on my own. It was an issue with resolution caching. Will update this ticket in a minute

Comment: The AWS API posts to / and has no arguments for reference, otherwise you would be very much correct.

Comment: $request_uri already contains the args. No need to add $is_args$args